# Is this a good code to calculate a chance in %?

Tags: php, math

Is this the right code to calculate a chance of 25%?

```
if(rand(1,100) < 25){
    echo 'succes';
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

And if the chance for success should be 3,5%, I can change the 25 to 3.5?

Or is this better?

```
if (25 >= mt_rand(1,100)){
    echo 'succes';
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: use [mt_rand](http://php.net/mt_rand) for better random values

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) and use your method with one decimal value you can use the following:

```
if(rand(1, 1000) <= 35) {
```

Comment: being pedantic: if you want to start from zero you should only go to 999

Comment: Or is this better:     if (25 >= mt_rand(1,100)){
        echo 'succes';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }

Answer (score 1):

I think to be pedantic you would want:

```
if(rand(1,100) <= 25) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

ie you are drawing from a set of 100 numbers; 25 of which are counted as success so P(success) = 25%

The [docs for rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) say it returns an int, so to do fractions you will need to scale, eg for 3.5%:

```
if(rand(1,1000) <= 35) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

As others have suggested, you can also use [mt_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) as a direct substitute for rand.  According to the docs, it can be four times faster than rand, and uses the popular and well behaved [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) pseudo random number generator.

Using left hand comparisons, ie swapping the constant and function call and reversing the comparison operator is a common component of many [coding conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions). This is used as a technique to prevent subtle assignment bugs when an assignment (=) is accidentally used instead of equals (==).

Comment: if you are generating dozens and dozens of them you may want to since the results will be less correlated.  Otherwise, I doubt you'll notice

Comment: Thanks, is this code good?:     if (25 >= mt_rand(1,100)){
        echo 'succes';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }

Comment: Yep, same result. Personally I find expressing things that way harder to think about, but a lot of people use it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do your calculation of percentage chance in a separate function and return the answer into a variable in the main section of your code then use an if statement to check it is greater than or equal to 25%. Just my two cents. Hope it helps.